# Terminology of "algebraically closed rings"

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, field-theory, symmetric-polynomials, integral-extensions

There are various approaches how to generalize the notion of an algebraically closed field to the context of commutative rings. A good survey is [R. Raphael, On algebraic closures](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43737179). I am interested in the following notion of an "algebraically closed" commutative ring $R$, which is not exactly covered there:

- Every monic polynomial over $R$ decomposes as a product product of linear factors.

This is related to the notion studied in [E. Enochs, Totally integrally closed rings](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1968-019-03/S0002-9939-1968-0224600-9/S0002-9939-1968-0224600-9.pdf), but not identical to it (in the non-reduced case).

**Question.** Is there an established name for commutative rings satisfying the property above? Can you name some literature where these rings have been studied?

Notice that I am not interested in literature about related notions (Raphael's paper mentions a couple of them), I am asking specifically about this notion.

Let me mention the following existence result: Every commutative ring $R$ admits a tight integral extension $R \hookrightarrow S$ such that $S$ is "algebraically closed" in the sense above. (Notice that this result holds in Enochs's setting only when $R$ is reduced.)

Comment: Just wanted to add that these are called "absolutely integrally closed" rings in the Stacks Project [Tag 0DCK](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DCK).

Comment: Related [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/130520/242) (also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2043948/242) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/292119)). It would be helpful to add a definition of a "tight" extension.

Comment: Thank you! The term "absolutely integrally closed" is also used in the book "Integral Closure of Ideals, Rings, and Modules" by Swanson-Huneke in Bill's link. You may post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been answered in the comments. They are called "absolutely integrally closed" rings.

PS: I have posted a follow-up question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434038).